# how to get minimum price from posted custom fields of posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

This is my code (So how will i get lowest price from posts)

```
  <div>
```

it is getting subcategories from parent category

```
    <?php 
    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of='.$cat.'&hide_empty');
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    ?>
```

> ---

```
 <div class="cat-con">
          <?php
          $subCatId=sprintf('%s',$subcategory->term_id); //the_content(); 
          query_posts('cat='.$subCatId.'&order=ASC&meta_key=price&orderby=meta_value_number');
```

this part of code is getting me price of custom fields

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

      /************************************************************************/

      $price=$post->ID; 
      $price = get_post_meta($price, 'price', true);
      if ($price <= 3500) {
      $minPrice=$price;
      /************************************************************************/
          ?>
```

> ---

```
     <div class="cat-img">
     <?php $postID=$post->ID; $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src (get_post_thumbnail_id( $pageID ),'medium', true) ; ?>
     <img width="445" height="209" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" />
     </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <div class="cat-heading">
                      <?php echo sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));?></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <div class="cat-con-text">
                      <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>

                  <div>
                      <div class="floatright">
                          <a href="<?php echo sprintf('%s',get_category_link($subcategory->term_id)); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' );?>/images/btn-view.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="cat-price">Price Start From &pound;<?php echo $minPrice?></div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>
                      <?php    
              } // end if $price
              endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php } //end foreach; ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--End Category-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'll echo `$minPrice` at the bottom (outside of the loop):

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

/************************************************************************/

$price=$post->ID; 
$price = get_post_meta($price, 'price', true);

if ( !isset( $minPrice ) || $price < $minPrice )
    $minPrice = $price;

/************************************************************************/
```

Comment: `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$price1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", false);
echo $minPrice = min($price1);
endwhile;
`

/********************************************/
It is getting me value array
Array ( [0] => 2500 )
Array ( [0] => 3500 )

Comment: That's because you put 'false' as the 3rd parameter: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: And using min() is useless in an array that only has 1 value: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) (unless if you have multiple values in the "price" meta key).

Answer (score 0):

```
`while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$price1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", false);
echo $minPrice = min($price1);
endwhile;
`
```

/********************************************/

```
It is getting me value array
Array ( [0] => 2500 )
Array ( [0] => 3500 )
```